# how to debug/make angular app run on phantomjs/prerenderio

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, prerender

I know it may sound crazy but yeah, I thought making angular work on old IEs was crazy enough. The reason why is that our app are running fine on most browsers (laptop and fone). Now it is not working with prerenderio (which depends on phantomjs).

Note: not the whole app having the problem but just a few routes.  I tried to comment our the code of that route but it still giving $rootScope/infdig.

I have been debuging it for 2 days before asking. I really need some hint what to do

Comment: You'll have to add some more details mate. Can you create a plunkr with a demo of the code that's not working? Can you isolate the code that's not working and post that? I don't know ... but like this it's unlikely you'll get an answer.

Comment: I know :( . But I can't pin-point the "bad" code. So I guess maybe phantomjs is like old IE, just doesn't work for no reason... I don't know... What I need is more like some hints, rather than code debugging..

Comment: Try different PhantomJS versions: 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 2.0.0 (upgrade & downgrade).

Comment: Well ... what I usually do when I can't find the root cause is this: I remove code until if I remove some more,  I can't reproduce the problem - in an attempt to isolate the problem area. Maybe it's a specific file ... maybe it's happening when I include a service.. That's my approach to a situation like this.